# Rails 7, vips on M1 MacBook Air

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, vips

I'm unable to use Rails 7.0.3.1 with vips on an M1 MacBook Air due to the error:

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: Could not open library 'glib-2.0.0': dlopen(glib-2.0.0, 0x0005): tried: 'glib-2.0.0' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0.0' (no such file), '/usr/lib/glib-2.0.0' (no such file), '/Users/brody/Code/tms.next-tms.com.wip2/glib-2.0.0' (no such file).
Could not open library '/opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib': dlopen(/opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
```

I'm using ffi 1.15.1 and can see it searching correctly in `/opt/local/lib`, but the homebrew package builds binaries for x86_64 rather than arm64e even while using the `--build-from-source` option (`brew install vips --build-from-source`).

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: vips should be native m1 with homebrew, see https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vips --- perhaps your brew needs updating?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue (with libglib-2.0.0) but then I figured that brew poured `glib--2.74.5.arm64_monterey.bottle` so why does it find 2.0.0? In my case it was (a dated version of) Navicat linking an old glib

```
~$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libglib*
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 chaos  staff    73B Dec 11 11:23 /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib -> /Applications/Navicat Premium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
```

This wasn't the only file however, Navicat linked a total of 71 dylib files. I removed all those symlinks and then the error disappeared

Comment: Had this issue plus a few other lib symlinks to remove - part of the joy of migrating from an older laptop instead of a fresh install :-)